# how to fetch the value from other state using primary key value in one state using custom query in corda

Tags: corda

I am trying to get the value from other state using the primary key in the current state using a custom query. i couldn't find a way to where to start and what to use. I read about valutqueryby. but no idea about the custom query. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I am doing it is during creation of your second state you put your first state linear ID into the state, then:-

```
val generalCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED) 

val firstLinearIdExpression = builder { (SecondSchemaV1.SecondEntity::orderfirstLinearId).equal(firstLinearId.id.toString()) }

val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<Second>(generalCriteria .and(QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(firstLinearIdExpression))).states
```

then you will get your results from your vault.